# How to group array of objects and update the state in react React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state that contains an array of objects. I added `order` so I can group the object based on the order. A new bunch of objects will be created when a button is clicked and the new objects `order` value will increase

```
const initialData = [
  {
    name: "point",
    label: "Point",
    order: 1
  },
  {
    name: "optionA",
    label: "A",
    order: 1
  },
  {
    name: "optionB",
    label: "B",
    order: 1
  },
];
```

Here is what I tried. I used `reduce` to group the data based on `order` when a button is clicked. The order value changes but the array the new array is not populating

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialData)

const addMoreField = () => {
    const groups = formData.reduce(
      (groups, item) => ({
        ...groups,
        [item.order]: [
          ...(groups[item.order] || []),
          { ...item, order: item.order++ }
        ]
      }),
      {}
    );

setFormData(groups)

 console.log("groups", groups);
    console.log("formData", formData);
}
```

The `addMoreField` function is supposed to increment the order and create a new array with more groups.

```
const newData = [
1: [
  {
    name: "point",
    label: "Point",
    order: 1
  },
  {
    name: "optionA",
    label: "A",
    order: 1
  },
  {
    name: "optionB",
    label: "B",
    order: 1
  },
],

2: [
  {
    name: "point",
    label: "Point",
    order: 2
  },
  {
    name: "optionA",
    label: "A",
    order: 2
  },
  {
    name: "optionB",
    label: "B",
    order: 2
  },
]
]
```

implementation on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-sound-rj5z1h?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Change it to `item.order+1`, `item.order++` increments `order` in the original state (which is not good), but returns the value of `item.order` before any increment occurs

Comment: I did but i am not getting new groups of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Not sure if I fully understand the goal, but I did some modification in the posted sandbox so that the solution in the original answer is wired up with existing code.

Also modified the `onChange` handler a bit so that it correctly record data to `state` object for the output with `submit`.

Forked demo with modifications: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-field-xlxsdm?file=/src/App.js)

Firstly the use of initial value changed so that it can be properly mapped:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState([initialData]);
```

Also changed the format for `map()` as the following. The `onChange` is modified so that it accepts value from multiple fields to add to the state object:

```
<form>
  <div className="wrapper">
    {formData.map((field, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <p>{`field ${index + 1}`}</p>
        {field.map((data, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="form-data">
            <label>{data.name}</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name={data.name}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setState((prev) => ({
                  ...prev,
                  [data.order]: {
                    ...prev[data.order],
                    [data.name]: e.target.value,
                  },
                }))
              }
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
</form>
```

**Original**

It seems that the posted `initialData` is an array but the `newData` looks like an object. According to description in the question, perhaps it should be an array of "group" but adding a new group with `order + 1` in the desired result?

The below example modifies `addMoreField` so that it first find the latest `order` from old groups, and then return a new array adding the new group with `latestOrder + 1`.

Some lists of initial and new data are also added but they're for testing only.

This example runs in snippets for convenience:

```js
const initialData = [
  {
    name: "point",
    label: "Point",
    order: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "optionA",
    label: "A",
    order: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "optionB",
    label: "B",
    order: 1,
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState(initialData);

  const addMoreField = () =>
    setFormData((prev) => {
      const oldGroups = Array.isArray(prev[0]) ? [...prev] : [[...prev]];
      const latestOrder = oldGroups.reduce(
        (acc, cur) => (cur[0].order > acc ? cur[0].order : acc),
        0
      );
      const newGroup = oldGroups[0].map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        order: latestOrder + 1,
      }));
      return [...oldGroups, newGroup];
    });

  return (
    <main>
      <button onClick={addMoreField}>ADD GROUP</button>
      <section>
        <div>
          <h3> initialData: </h3>
          {initialData.map((item, index) => (
            <ul key={index}>
              <li>{`name: ${item.name}`}</li>
              <li>{`label: ${item.label}`}</li>
              <li>{`order: ${item.order}`}</li>
            </ul>
          ))}
        </div>
        {Array.isArray(formData[0]) && (
          <div>
            <h3> Current formData (newData): </h3>
            {formData.map((group, index) => (
              <React.Fragment key={index}>
                {group.map((item, index) => (
                  <ul key={index}>
                    <li>{`name: ${item.name}`}</li>
                    <li>{`label: ${item.label}`}</li>
                    <li>{`order: ${item.order}`}</li>
                  </ul>
                ))}
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <App />
);
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  gap: 80px;
}

button {
  padding: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. It gives me the expected output. However I used useEffect to load the `Current formData`  when the page loads, but the data render multiple times. I would like the form to display instantly when the page loads and subsequently clicking on the button to add more filed

Comment: @Haq Indeed this only considered the posted scenario where initial data is given. Perhaps share some more details about the use case so that we can see if  we might be possible to help?

Comment: I have added codesandbox link to the question. The use case is when a user want to submit batch data. In this scenario when a button is clicked a copy of that field should display and the data can be summited at once

Comment: @Haq Thanks for the update, not sure if I fully understand the goal but I wired up the sandbox code with the solution from the answer, so that it might be further adjusted to meet desired result. Details are updated in the answer as well and hopefully it could help.